# C# - How to convert Func<T, bool> to Func<dynamic, bool>?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection, converters, func

Im using Entity Framework 4, I have an entity

```
public partial class UserEntity : EntityObject 
{
    public string id_user;
    public string pass;
    public DateTime date_added;
}
```

and a data transfer object with custom attributes

```
[DataTransferObject("UserEntity")]
public class User
{
    [EntityColumn("id_user")]
    public string idUser { get; set; }
    [EntityColumn("pass")]
    public string password { get; set; }
    [EntityColumn("date_added")]
    public string dateAdded { get; set; }
}
```

I convert the entity to dto and the dto to entity using these attributes with reflection, I'm using a generic repository for data access methods, when I want to make a query, using `Enumerable.Where`, to the `ObjectSet` of the entity, this require a `Func<dynamic, bool>` (dynamic because the program doesn't know the entity implementing the repository), this works but I want a `Func<DTObject, bool>` as parameter so I don't have to use entities in business layer, is there a way to achieve something like this?

```
public static Func<dynamic, bool> ConvertFunc<DTObject>(Func<DTObject, bool> predicate)
{
    /* do some magic to convert func */
    return newFunc;
}

Func<dynamic, bool> newFunc = ConvertFunc<User>(u => u.idUser == "admin" && u.password == "abc123");
/* newFunc = u => u.id_user == "admin" && u.pass == "abc123" */
```

Comment: Maybe if you use `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` you could do it. But why not just make it `ConvertFunc<T>(Func<dynamic, bool>`?

Comment: I would really not recommend taking this route. Writing queries against your DTO's and then dynamically transforming those into queries for your entities? I've no doubt it can be done (C# is crazy enough to allow you to do this) but I would seriously reconsider exposing your entity objects to the objects that will contain your query logic.

Answer (score 2):

I need to stop you right here. You are completely wrong on your approach. You need to use `Queryable.Where<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, bool>>)` for `EntityFramework` to work. The method you would actually be using is `Enumerable.Where<T>(this IEnumerable<T> set, Func<T, bool> predicate)`, which would do the filtering IN MEMORY. This means the road you are going down will download your entire table into memory.

For this to work you need to be playing with the `System.Linq.Expressions` namespace. However, if this is going to work, without some insane amount of logic (more than already exists with Expressions). Your Dto signature will be exactly the same as your `EntityObject`.

Given this is true, what value does your DTO add (given the maintenance cost of the class)?

The only value I see is the decoupling of your domain logic from your data storage (ie you don't have `EntityObject` in your domain layer). However that problem was solved years ago with POCOs.

TLDR

XY problem. Use POCO instead.